# grep lines that contains only numbers or only letters characters until a delimiter

Tags: regex, unix, grep

Kind of a confusing title, but let me explain.
I have a tab delimited file that contains lines in the following format (columns are delimited by tab)

```
Extra   573102|000473
Extra   ZRY|BC95624
Missing ABC|BC99000
Missing 123456|001122
```

I'd like to split the file to 4 different files, based on the following logic:

1. If line contains "Extra" and only numbers until the "|", put that line in file #1 (In the above case, file #1 will contain "Extra   573102|000473").
2. If line contains "Extra" and only letters until the "|", put that line in file #2 (In the above case, file #2 will contain "Extra   ZRY|BC95624").
3. If line contains "Missing" and only numbers until the "|", put that line in file #3 (In the above case, file #3 will contain "Missing   ABC|BC99000").
4. If line contains "Missing" and only letters until the "|", put that line in file #4 (In the above case, file #4 will contain "Missing   123456|001122").

I have no idea how to combine the text, tab character and the regex that will accomplish the above.

Comment: You're aware you need to show some kind of attempt at this, aren't you?

Comment: In addition to @LucasTrzesniewski, you swapped point 3 and 4

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I agree, but since I haven't had the slightest idea on how to combine regex, grep and tab characters, I didn't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some dummy code:

```
regex1 = "^Extra\h+\d+\|"
# This is Extra at the beginning of the string / line in multiline mode
# followed by spaces and digits up to the | character
regex2 = "^Extra\h+[a-zA-Z]+\|"
# same with letters
regex3 = "^Missing\h+\d+\|"
regex4 = "^Missing\h+[a-zA-Z]+\|"

if line matches regex1:
    append to file1
else if line matches regex2:
    append to file2
else if line matches regex3:
    append to file3
else if line matches regex4:
    append to file4
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tD1qS0/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F'[\t |]+' '$1=="Extra" {
    if ($2~/^[0-9]+$/) print >> "file1"
    else
    if ($2~/^[A-Z]+$/) print >> "file2"
    next
}

$1=="Missing" {
    if ($2~/^[0-9]+$/) print >> "file3"
    else
    if ($2~/^[A-Z]+$/) print >> "file4"
}' yourfile
```